# Jython: get image dimensions from URL

Tags: python, jython

I'm new to Jython (but not to Python) and I'm trying to get the dimensions of an image from a URL.

For example the input would be https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg

and it would return (600, 400).

I know in Python it can be done with `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests
data = requests.get(url).content
im = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
print(im.size)
```

But how to do this in Jython since `PIL` is not supported by Jython?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class.

```
from java.net import URL
from javax.imageio import ImageIO

img = ImageIO.read(URL("https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg"))
print img.getWidth()
print img.getHeight()
```